# LDAP Configuration on Windows 2016

Tags: ldap, configuration, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd 20.04 on a Windows 2016 server and would like to integrate AD. I can not seem to find where to put the server info

Answer (score 0):

I know little of LDAP, and almost nothing of AD, but found in the ejabberd Docs site this section: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/database-ldap/#active-directory

Comment: Thank you. I found that info but not sure where to add the information. Which configuration file

Comment: In general, all the documentation in https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/ goes to ejabberd.yml